# Bring QProcess window to front (running Qt Assistant)

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

My Qt application starts a QProcess that runs Qt Assistant.

I am using Linux (Ubuntu/Neon/KDE) but I want the Qt application to run on Windows and other Linux distributions as well.

Now I need a function that allows to bring the Assistant main window to front at the desktop.

I could not find a solution doing this using the QProcess object. Also I could not find a way to do this via Qt Assistant remote control.

How can I do this in a portable way?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is showing `qhc` help files along with your application, you can have a look at the [Qt Help module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthelp-index.html), which is used by [Assistant](https://github.com/qt/qttools/tree/5.11/src/assistant/assistant) itself.

> Instead of showing the help in an external application like the Qt
>   Assistant, it is also possible to embed the online help in the
>   application. The contents can then be retrieved via the QHelpEngine
>   class and can be displayed in nearly any form. Showing the help in a
>   QTextBrowser is probably the most common way, but embedding it in
>   What's This help is also perfectly possible.

More [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthelp-framework.html#using-qhelpengine-api)